# Azure API Management Operation URL Template

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to create a simple, parameterless, web api endpoint managed by Azure API Management. My question is I when I add a paramaterless operation, what in the world is the URL template supposed to be? My endpoint is http://airport-api2.azurewebsites.net/api/airport. There are no parameters, the service works fine outside of API Management. I created an API Management and want to add this GET to my azurewebsites endpoint. What is the mandatory URL Template value I need to enter into the API Management portal to get this thing to work. The built in echo service uses /resource. I cannot find an example. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the API with these parameters

- WebService URL : http://airport-api2.azurewebsites.net/api
- WebAPi suffix url : whatyouwant

then configure the operation with

- operation : /airport

Enjoy!